# php curl CURLOPT_HEADER and DOM

Tags: php, dom, curl

I have the following code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  $html = curl_exec($ch);


  preg_match_all('|Set-Cookie: (.*);|U', $html, $results);  
  $cookies = implode(';', $results[1]);


  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom->loadHTML($html);
```

on line **$dom->loadHTML($html);** I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [function.DOMDocument-loadHTML]:
Misplaced DOCTYPE declaration in
Entity, line: 12 in
D:\Programs\xampp\xampp\htdocs\ip\megafonmoscow.php
on line 39

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML()
[function.DOMDocument-loadHTML]:
htmlParseStartTag: misplaced 
tag in Entity, line: 13 in
D:\Programs\xampp\xampp\htdocs\ip\megafonmoscow.php
on line 39

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML()
[function.DOMDocument-loadHTML]:
htmlParseStartTag: misplaced 
tag in Entity, line: 14 in
D:\Programs\xampp\xampp\htdocs\ip\megafonmoscow.php
on line 39

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML()
[function.DOMDocument-loadHTML]:
Unexpected end tag : head in Entity,
line: 32 in
D:\Programs\xampp\xampp\htdocs\ip\megafonmoscow.php
on line 39

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML()
[function.DOMDocument-loadHTML]:
htmlParseStartTag: misplaced 
tag in Entity, line: 34 in
D:\Programs\xampp\xampp\htdocs\ip\megafonmoscow.php
on line 39
```

Is the line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);` cause of this error? I need it because of the cookies. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove that line so that it won't return headers and then use the [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) functions to get them after the curl request.

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  $html = curl_exec($ch);
  $headers=get_headers($host, 1);
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the get_headers() function makes a separate request to the URL - so you may get different results depending on what you do with SSL, and you certainly will if you're sending any POST with your cURL (not relevant to this example but worth noting)

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to mck89's approach is to download headers and body together, but to split them before you try to parse it:

```
$html = curl_exec($ch);

[snip]

$html = preg_replace('/^.*\n\n/s','',$html,1); // strip out everything before & including the double line break between headers and body

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

This saves an HTTP request and therefore a certain amount of time.